# Firestore Paging Adapter- How to know if query returns 0 results

Tags: java, android, firebase, pagination, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using firestore paging adapter to populate my `RecyclerView` with data from Firestore, if collection in Firestore is empty I would like to show a `TextView` to inform user about that, if it is not then I would like to populate `EecyclerView` with data but I don't see a way to do this with Firestore paging adapter because I can't acces data from inside the fragment where I create adapter
Im my `Fragment` inside `onViewCreated`

```
val config = PagedList.Config.Builder()
                .setEnablePlaceholders(false)
                .setPrefetchDistance(2)
                .setPageSize(5)
                .build()
        val options = FirestorePagingOptions.Builder<Question>()
                .setLifecycleOwner(viewLifecycleOwner)
                .setQuery(FirestoreUtil.myFeedQuery, config, Question::class.java)
                .build()
        mAdapter = WallFeedRVAdapter(this, options)
```

WallFeedRVAdapter is `RecyclerView` adapter where I populate `MyViewHolder` with loaded data. How can I from this current fragment that hosts `RecyclerView` know if myFeedQuery returned any results so I can update recyclerView visibility to GONE and emptyInfoTextView to VISIBLE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the number of items that are returned by the query which is passed to the `FirestorePagingOptions` object, you need to use `getItemCount()` method that exist in your adapter class. Because the data from Cloud Firestore is loaded asynchronously, you cannot simply call `getItemCount()` directly in your adapter class, as it will always be **zero**. So in order to get the total number of items, you need to register an observer like in the following lines of code:

```
mAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
    public void onItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
        int totalNumberOfItems = adapter.getItemCount();
        Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(totalNumberOfItems));
        if(totalNumberOfItems == 0) {
            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            emptyInfoTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: In my case, It doesn't work when items == 0, but works fine when the number of  items is greater than zero, can you help?

Comment: @Xylan Without seeing your code, I'm afraid I cannot much of a help. So please post another fresh question using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: The onItemRangeInserted method seems to be called only when an item is inserted into the adapter, but in the case there is no item to be added, this method isnt even being called

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by simple code. Just override `onLoadingStateChangedListner` method inside your `FirestorePagingAdapter` and then use `getItemCount`.
I implemented it as follow -

```
@Override
protected void onLoadingStateChanged(@NonNull LoadingState state) {
    switch (state){
        case LOADED:
        case FINISHED:
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if(getItemCount() == 0) {
                emptyIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                recyclerview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            break;
    }
    super.onLoadingStateChanged(state);
}
```

Comment: Helpful when checking getItemCount() == 0.

Comment: There's no method to overide in Pagination 3

Answer (score -1):

solved issue with registerAdapterDataObserver

Comment: Is this different from the accepted answer, which already uses `registerAdapterDataObserver`? If so, how is it different? This reads more like a comment than an actual answer to the question.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).