# Get the Highest 10 Value's From Database and show in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have UID inside of Top Child. Under Top Child i have 2 more child : Name and Exchange . I want to get the Top Exchange values And show them in recyclerview . The highest exchange will be in the top ,second top will be in second position and third will be in third  . I am getting all values serially with firebaserecycleradapter .But i want to get the hightest value to lowest.

here is database structure : [image]

here is class:

```
TopRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Top");
        recyclerView = views.findViewById(R.id.topRec);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);


        Query query = TopRef.orderByChild("Exchange").limitToLast(20);
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<TopAdapter>()
                .setQuery(query,TopAdapter.class)
                .build();


        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<TopAdapter, TopFragment.TopAdapterHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final TopFragment.TopAdapterHolder holder, int position, @NonNull TopAdapter model) {
                String userIds = getRef(position).getKey();
                assert userIds != null;
                TopRef.child(userIds).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("Name")){
                            String name = dataSnapshot.child("Name").getValue(String.class);
                            Long exchange = dataSnapshot.child("Exchange").getValue(Long.class);




                            holder.Name.setText(name);
                            holder.Exchange.setText(String.valueOf(exchange));




                        }


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });

            }




            @NonNull
            @Override
            public TopFragment.TopAdapterHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.topview,viewGroup,false);
                return new TopFragment.TopAdapterHolder(view);
            }
        };



        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Here is adapter class:

```
public class TopAdapter {
    String Name;
    String Exchange;



    public TopAdapter() {

    }


    public TopAdapter(String name, String exchange) {
        Name = name;
        Exchange = exchange;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public String getExchange() {
        return Exchange;
    }
}
```

Crash Log: Found two getters or fields with conflicting case sensitivity for property: exchange

Comment: Instead of describing how you database looks like, please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least as a screenshot.

Comment: @AlexMamo Bro i don't have any data now. That's why wrote structure

Comment: @AlexMamo check

Comment: How is `TopRef` defined?

Comment: TopRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Top");

Comment: And you want to get all those objects within `Top` child according to the highest value of your `Exchange` property right?

Comment: Yes . From top to low in this format . and 20 object only.

Comment: Ok, I'll write you an answer right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to order data in descending order would be on the client-side. In order to get all those objects within your `Top` child according to the highest value of your `Exchange` property, first, you need to use a query and then choose one of three options. So instead of passing `TopRef` to your `setQuery()` method, pass the following query:

```
Query query = TopRef.orderByChild("Exchange").limitToLast(20);
```

As you can see, using this query Firebase orders the results in ascending order by a given property by default. There is no method in Firebase to order in descending order but there are few tweaks that can be made.

If you are using a `RecyclerView` to display data, the simplest way would be to use the following code:

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

This approach will reverse the order directly in your `RecyclerView`.

Another approach would be to create your own adapter that extends `FirebaseListAdapter` and override `getItem()` method.

Another approach would be to get the data from the database, add it to a `Collection`, a `List` would be a good solution and then use `Collections.reverse(yourList);`. In this case, you'll lose Firebase-UI's features.

**Edit:**

```
FirebaseRecyclerOptions options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<TopAdapter>()
        .setQuery(query,TopAdapter.class) //Changed
        .build();
```

Comment: Can you tell me where i should add the query ? As my code i already have a query right?

Comment: No, you don't have a query. Your `TopRef` is a simple reference, **not** a query. You should use a query so you can order/limit the results. There is no other way you can do that.

Comment: Can you modify my code? As if a query the value how can i show in recyclerview . I am not familiar with query and firebase recycycler adapter.

Comment: With what message?

Comment: Wait i am uploading the full class.

Comment: That's totally another issue which should new considered another question but since you're new, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069574/firebase-android-listview-not-being-displayed) out.

Comment: So knowing that the initial problem is solved, I will ask you now to accept my answer. I'd appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: And it also showing 0 value child which i don't want to.