# How to get count of elements present in FirebaseListAdapter?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I am using `FirebaseListAdapter` for the `ListView` and it is perfectly working fine. I have an additional requirement to display the count of elements present in the `ListView`. How do I do that?

I read through the documentation of `FirebaseListAdapter` and found that there is a method `getCount()` which is supposed to return the count of elements. But it is always returning zero. Below is the code I have. What am I missing?

```
    mAppointmentAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Appointment>(options) {

    @Override
        public void populateView(View view, Appointment appointment, int position) {

            TextView nameTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.app_patient_name_view);
            TextView reasonTextView = 

         ...         
        }

    };
    appointmentListView.setAdapter(mAppointmentAdapter);

    // Display count of appointments
    int mAppointmentsCount;
    mAppointmentsCount = mAppointmentAdapter.getCount();
    mAppointmentsCountView.setText(String.valueOf(mAppointmentsCount));
```

Need the count of elements in the `ListView` or the adapter.

Comment: Try calling it inside populateView(), maybe data loading still in progress while you calling getCount();

Comment: Firebase API's are asynchronous. In `FirebaseListAdapter` class, you're going to get a call for `populateView()` method for every child at that location. Have you tried to simply create inside the class a counter and increment it in `populateView()` method?

Comment: If you intend to use a `RecyclerView` instead of a `ListView`, then check my answer from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57587615/hide-recyclerview-when-there-is-no-item/57587887#57587887)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Alex has the correct idea here: most likely the items haven't been loaded from the database yet when you call `mAppointmentAdapter.getCount()`, so it correctly returns `0`.

That call should likely be inside `populateView` as Alex said, or in the [`onDataChanged` method](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md#data-and-error-events) of your adapter. The `onDataChanged` gets called by FirebaseUI whenever it has updated the data, so that is the perfect place to also update your counter:

```
@Override
public void onDataChanged() {
  int mAppointmentsCount = mAppointmentAdapter.getCount();
  mAppointmentsCountView.setText(String.valueOf(mAppointmentsCount));
}
```

If this knowledge doesn't allow you to solve the problem, please edit your question to show *when*/*where* that call to `mAppointmentAdapter.getCount()` exists, as it makes it more likely we can help.

Answer (score 0):

I had missed that Firebase API's are asynchronous. Used the onDataChanged() method given above by Frank. Worked like a charm.