# How to hide a Firestore RecyclerView if empty

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

I'm new to Android development. Currently, I'm using Firestore UI to populate a RecyclerView. It works properly but now I want to hide/show dynamically the RecyclerView if it doesn't contain data or when something is inserted. Overriding the method onDataChanged in my adapter class I noticed that I can properly detect dynamiccally if the number of items in my adapter is 0 or not. How can I use this to make visible or not my recyclerview?

[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. You'll also need to show us a bit more context.

Answer (score 2):

One simple way would be to tell the recycler view to hide itself:

```
mRecyclerView.setVisibility(getItemCount() != 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
```

Comment: The point is that if I check the number of elements outside the Adapter class (for example in the class where my RecyclerView is defined and used), it always results that there are no elements...

Comment: @PCNF That's the expected behavior since data is loaded from Firebase asynchronous. In order to get the number of items, you need to [register an observer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57441563/firestore-paging-adapter-how-to-know-if-query-returns-0-results). Besides that, you can also use [onChanged()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63783965/firestore-recyclerview-itemcount-returns-0) method exactly for the same purpose.

Comment: @AlexMamo As I already said, as also said in the answer you linked to me, I override the onDataChanged method (the one you see in the picture) in the adapter class. Thanks to the code you see I can correctly obtain in real time the number of elements contained. But how do I hide the RecyclerView that is present in the main activity using that method?

Comment: @PCNF Simply by [registering an observer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57441563/firestore-paging-adapter-how-to-know-if-query-returns-0-results). If you don't want to use this solution, you can create your own callback.

Comment: @AlexMamo Tried to implement the same code in that answer. It's never triggered...

Comment: @PCNF Without seeing the code, we cannot be much of a help. So please post a new question using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can take a look at it.